# Is there any way to test methods involving evaluatePolicy(:localizedReason:reply:)

Tags: ios, swift, tdd, xctest, touch-id

I'm working with LocalAuthentication and `evaluatePolicy(:localizedReason:reply:)`. I'd like to tests this methods.
Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a protocol stub for it and not perform the test with integration to the real implementation.